# How would the proposed "Directive on Copyright in the Digital Single Market" Article 13 affect Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, legal, copyright

Under the proposed (and looking likely to pass) new copyright directive of the EU, any content hosters on the Internet would be fully liable for any copyright infringement committed on their services by users unless they implement automatic filtering to detect and pre-empt copyrighted content that would be used.

How would this work on Stack Exchange in practice?

- How could a content filter distinguish between licensed use of copyrighted material (code etc.) and unlicensed use?
- How could a content filter distinguish between fair and acceptable use and unacceptable misuse?
- Would it even be worth it for stack exchange to customize the filter for every SE site? I'd imagine movies.SE would need a vastly different content filter then apple.SE then stackoverflow.com

And further

- Does Stack Exchange plan on implementing such a filter? How's it looking so far?
- Have any preparations been made if the directive passes?
- Is Stack Exchange going to take an "if complained remove" attitude to potential rightsholders submitting complaints to limit liability?

From my reading of the proposed law it might be cheaper and more realistic for stack exchange to block european traffic outright rather then to try and comply with such a law, but I really hope that doesn't come to pass.

Comment: @Laurel My question is specifically asking about the impact and plans of stack exchange for a single article of the new proposal, while the one you linked is just general discussion about the proposal.

Comment: The EU representatives I spammed about this all believed this article should be removed from the directive. This will be a test if those EU politicians are reliable ...